# Which version of Fortran was the first to print backtraces?

Tags: fortran

I went through the [first Fortran manual](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/ibm/704/704_FortranProgRefMan_Oct56.pdf) and didn't see anything about a backtrace being printed on abnormal termination.

Did that exist in the first version, or was it implemented later?

Comment: I think that this was not defined by the language, but was a feature (or not) of a specific implementation/platform.

Comment: I wonder when the first backtrace was printed _at all_, regardless of language.  Can't remember when I first saw one.  It wasn't a thing for assembly language programmers.  And early Fortran programmers didn't have a _stack_.  Routines were not recursive.  Memory dumps didn't include backtraces because they were provided by the OS which didn't know about programming language runtimes.  I bet FORTRAN programmers had to make do with marking up dumps by hand like assembly coders for a long long time.  Probably COBOL too?  As a guess I'd bet LISP programmers saw them first.

Comment: @davidbak Backtraces were in Lisp 1.5

Comment: @davidbak I think so.  Some Fortran compilers worked by emitting assembly, so you would tell the assembler to print a listing with a symbol table, tell the linker (if there was one) to print out base addresses, then take the abort address and work back from there.  It sounds like a lot, but it wasn't that bad.

Comment: @WayneConrad that's exactly what I meant by marking up dumps.  I did a lot of it for assembly language.  You put little rectangles around interesting values and drew arrows to other interesting values.  Your printout ended up looking like - well, one of those movies where the crazy paranoid guy has a corkboard on the wall with lots of pictures pinned up and marked up with different colored sharpies and yarn stretched from pin to pin in a big random graph ...

Comment: I don't think you will find anything about backtraces in the Fortran 2018 standard either (see section 5.3.7 in particular). As @WayneConrad says, this is a feature of some compilers.

Comment: I believe the KDF9 FORTRAN IV compiler, which emitted KAL4 assembly code, produced what I'd consider a backtrace, essentially just an octal dump of the subroutine jump nesting store (SJNS) which held return addresses. Address to routine mapping was manual by consulting the cross-reference output from compilation. I'd guess this was reasonably straightforward since, per the implementors, the compiler produced 'workmanlike code' where the KAL4 was closely related to the FORTRAN; in particular names carried over.

Comment: @davidbak exactly.  You can’t have a stack dump without a stack…

Comment: All languages (at least BAL, COBOL, FORTRAN and PL/I that I know of had ABEND dumps on DOS/VS and MVS in the 1970s, but those were more like core dumps printed on greenbar in hex.  Very useful if you knew what you were doing.

Comment: @RonJohn - but the question is about backtraces, not stack dumps. As long as you can follow a chain of return addresses you can produce a backtrace. For 'return link stored in word 0 of called routine' you just need enough additional information to map an instruction address to the address of the routine containing it.

Comment: @another-dave it's been 35 years, but IIRC mainframe ABEND dumps required one to know where to look.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that to answer this question, we have to find a few examples and decide which is earliest.

To that end, the System/360 OS FORTRAN IV level G compiler, from 1966, offers this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
| IHC219I                                          |
| TRACEBACK FOLLOWS   ROUTINE   ISN    REG. 14     |
|                     IBCOM            820068FC    |
|                     MASTR            00005378    |
|                     PAYROLL          00003148    |
| ENTRY POINT = 5000                               |
+--------------------------------------------------+
Figure 58. 
Sample Traceback for Execution-Time Errors
```

See page 82 in [C28-6639-1 FORTRAN IV G Programmers Guide](https://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/360/fortran/C28-6639-1_FORTRAN_IV_G_Programmers_Guide_1966.pdf).

The level H compiler has a similar facility, with a couple more registers displayed.